# Squid3 URL Block

Tags: linux, squid

I hope there are some squid experts.
I'm trying to configure my squid.conf file.
The configuration worked, but here is the problem:
When I try to block only one site, it blocks everything...

Here is my code:

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

acl biz_network src 10.1.42.0/24
acl biz_hours time M T W T F 9:00-17:00

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl fortytwo_network src 192.168.42.0/24
acl bad_url dstdomain .msn.com           #### THIS IS THE 1ST LINE THAT CAUSE A PROBLEM ####

http_access allow biz_network biz_hours
http_access allow fortytwo_network

http_access deny bad_url                 #### THIS IS THE 2ND LINE THAT CAUSE A PROBLEM ####

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 8080

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
visible_hostname BenNahmias
```

**The bold lines will make all URL's blocked**

Without these lines, I can access all URL's

My question is, what's the right order of the lines (those I marked) so only the site I choose will be blocked.

-- Thanks in advance, Orel.

Answer (score 1):

Heres another good example for those using acl blacklists to filter web content with squid proxy.

http://www.squidblacklist.org/downloads/squid.conf.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method :

delete this line :

```
acl bad_url dstdomain .msn.com
```

You have already added this line :

```
http_access deny bad_url
```

Make sure that you wrote your own dns blacklist related to bad_url acl here :

```
/etc/squid/bad-sites.squid
```

if you have no idea to implement, it looks like this :

```
.test.com
.badurl.net
```

For some website like facebook, it's better to use regex. Add this on your squid conf

```
acl fbban dstdom_regex facebook
http_access deny fbban
```

restart your squid

```
/sbin/service squid stop
/sbin/service squid start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/squid stop
/etc/init.d/squid restart
```